# Website with Written Equivalent of Shiurim?

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, internet, adult-learning

Is there a website that collects in-depth essays on Torah topics, or the written equivalent of shiurim?

I don't mean outreach sites like Chabad, Aish or SimpleToRemember, or public relations-oriented sites like Cross-Currents.

I mean sites analogous to YUTorah or Torah Downloads, that collect written material that is more or less the equivalent of the kinds of things that tend to be in shiurim. (This could include, for example, explanations of the daily daf, or detailed discussions of specific halachic or hashkafic issue or some aspect of the parshah.)

Comment: If you are willing to pay, you can get Techumin online                                     
[here](https://books.zomet.org.il)

Comment: Bein Din L'Din: http://bdld.info/

Answer (score 4):

VBM (virtual beit midrash) is exactly what you are describing.
https://www.etzion.org.il/en

Answer (score 3):

Try Iyun Hadaf in my opinion it's one of the best sites with amazing material .

Site:
https://dafyomi.co.il/section.php?gid=1&sid=7

Comment: If you're linking to their site, I that this feature: https://dafyomi.co.il/section.php?gid=1&sid=1 is closer to what the OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

[Hebrewbooks.org](https://hebrewbooks.org/) is such a site: it has collected lots of written lectures. [Here's an example of some such lectures.](https://hebrewbooks.org/39831)

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions made above are excellent, I would also reccomend exploring the Ohr Samayach Yeshiva's website https://ohr.edu/